# Master Key Malfunctioning (Bob the Robber 4)

Tags: bob-the-robber-4, crazygames.com

I'm currently playing **Bob the Robber 4** on the website **crazygames.com**, and when I have the **Master Key Gadget** equipped, and even though it says: "Unlocks all locked doors", I still have to lockpick them. Is it supposed to be like this, or is my game glitching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Master Key in Bob the Robber 4 by clicking the Master Key "gadget" icon on the top screen (fullscreen for Crazygames) and it will automatically unlock the door.

Comment: So basically, it's not automatic, you need to manually trigger the bonus action?